# ORDER BY using specific order in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have to display a table of data sorted by the following condition

First should be

Private field1 and field2 Match

Private field1  Match

Private

Non-Private field1  and field2  Match

Non-Private field1  Match

Non-Private

I'm very weak in SQL and only order by I know is

```
 select * 
 from sampleTable 
 order by field1
```

I know how to sort the data according to this order using C# and jQuery. Is there any way to accomplish the same using T-SQL?

The table is like this

```
id  field1  field2  private
---------------------------
316 test1   test    1
319 test2   NULL    0
320 test3   NULL    0
321 test4   test4   1
322 NULL    NULL    0
323 NULL    NULL    1
```

Comment: Could you show us your table design?

Comment: Please consider rephrasing your question. Conditions you mentioned are obscure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
SELECT * FROM sampleTable 
ORDER BY
  private DESC,
  CASE WHEN field1 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
  CASE WHEN field2 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

I'm assuming 'Match' means 'Not Null'?

**UPDATE**

I should point out that if non-null values in field1 and field2 are to be sorted too, then an additional sort clause is needed:

```
SELECT * FROM sampleTable 
ORDER BY
  private DESC,
  CASE WHEN field1 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, field1,
  CASE WHEN field2 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, field2
```

So, to explain it in a little more detail:

The `private` field comes first, and because it's sorted in descending order, rows marked private will come first. Effectively, we've now got two groups of rows that each move on to the next sort expression.

Unfortunately, sorting each by `field1` or `field2` will put NULLs first, which is not what you want. The `CASE` expression effectively sorts by '1' if it's NULL, and a '0' otherwise. This moves all the NULLs to the end, because 1 > 0. Now that they've been separated, we can further sort each group by the field value.

Answer (score 1):

Try the `case` solution if your condition depends on a column value

```
 select * from sampleTable
ORDER BY 
  CASE WHEN @columnA = 'X' AND @columnB = 'Z' THEN name 
  .
  .
  .
  .
  .
  .
  CASE WHEN @columnA = 'Y' AND @columnB = 'W' THEN name END
```

i don't really understand your conditions so i write it like an example but you can put whatever condition you want

Answer (score 1):

I completely misunderstood your question at first, here a new answer:

```
SELECT * from sampleTable ORDER BY
  private desc,
  CASE WHEN field1=field2 THEN 2  WHEN field1>'' THEN 1 END desc
```

Again the meaning of `'Match'` is unclear. But seeing you have accepted Michael's answer already I guess what you really mean is "is anything but not null". Then my version would be:

```
SELECT * from sampleTable ORDER BY
  private desc,
   CASE WHEN field1>='' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
  +CASE WHEN field2>='' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END desc,
  field1, field2
```

Comment: I just noticed that in my version `field1` and `field2` carry the same weight. In Michael McMullin's solution there is a clear preference on `field1`, which is what you want. So, the *correct* answer is Michael's! ;-)